# Connecting to a different database in Laravel based on connection url

Tags: laravel, database-connection, config, multi-database-connections

I've been tasked with making our Laravel code connect to a different database as the main database when the url is different. Our website is accessible by 2 urls:

`a.mycompany.com` and `b.mycompany.com`

I know the main database connection details are configured in `config/database.php`, but I've read that it's very much discouraged to try to conditionally change config variables there. Nonetheless, if I wanted to, could I check for the current url and change the connection details in that file? How would I do that?

Comment: almost like a multitenant application? also you can change config variables at run time if you wish, you are not altering the config files but you would have to reload the database connections

Comment: @lagbox yes i suppose that's conceptually really close to what i'm asking for.

Comment: Note that this application i have already exists, is already in production, and is huge - any solution would have to be one I can add onto an existing system, not one requiring development from scratch.

Comment: If this is multitenant perhaps you can use https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-multitenancy/v2/introduction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For these purposes, you need to configure the necessary connections in config/database.php. For example, for MySQL, add two connections:

```
'mysql_1' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

```
'mysql_2' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

Then directly in the code, use the desired connection:

```
$siteOne = DB::connection('mysql_1')->select(/* ... */);

$siteTwo = DB::connection('mysql_2')->select(/* ... */);

$siteTwo = (new User)->setConnection('mysql_2')->find(1);
```

To determine which domain it is, you can use suddomain routing:

```
Route::domain('{domain}.mycompany.com')->group(function () {
    // $domain variable
});
```

Then use $domain to check which site it is and use the correct connection.

It is also possible to establish a model-specific connection using the $connection property:

```
protected $connection = 'mysql_2';
```